# Tracking location in the background

Tags: android, background, location, tracking

I want to implement location tracking in android but in a small time interval (seconds), after searching and reading the documentation i found that there is restrictions on location access when app is in the background, and the solution is to use foreground service, But i need another legal and efficient solution without the need to show notification to the user.

Comment: You could use a work manager provided that you could only track the user at 15 mins intervals.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo thanks for your suggestion but i need the location update every minute at least

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that

```
public class GPSService extends Service {

private LocationListener listener;
private LocationManager locationManager;

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    return null;
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Intent i = new Intent("location_update");
            i.putExtra("coordinates",location);
            sendBroadcast(i);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,0,listener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
    }
}
}
```

And retreive by broadcaster

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i read that from android 8 there is restrictions on background services specially location updates. and my app needs to have accurate location updates every minute even if it's not currently running

Comment: @wageeh by your description of the desired behaviour it seems that you're going to have to rely on a foreground service with a permanent notification.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo  Yes sir that is my search conclusion, but i'm seeking another solution that i don't have to make my app has permanent notification.. but even the documentation suggest this solution.

Comment: @wageeh I know, I was merely suggesting that there is no alternative based on your requirements.